# Do I need floats, integers or string for my problem and how do i do that?

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner and im trying to make a code that does basic maths for someone:

```py
print('what shape do you need')
print('A:square or rectangle')
print('B: triangle')
print('C:circle')
answer =input()
if answer =='A':
  print ('enter first length')
  length1=input()
  print ('enter second length')
  length2=input()
  int('length1')
  int('length2')
  area=length1*length2
```

the problem I have is I don't know if I should turn the variables into integers, string or floats and if I did know I would know how to do that.
please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to Python! Take a look at this website: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to get you started and send you knocking on *exception handling*'s door. I will let you discover that on your own. For now, give the following a spin:

```
print('what shape do you need?')
print('A: square or rectangle')
print('B: triangle')
print('C: circle')
answer=input()
if answer =='A':
    length1 = float(input('enter first length::\t'))
    length2 = float(input('enter second length::\t'))
    print('area = {}'.format(length1*length2))
```

you can write cases `B` and `C` yourself based on the `A` example above.

Answer (score 0):

`length1=input()` would make length1 a string when you read the input.

Afterwards, I see that you do `int(length1)`, assuming that you intend to convert `length1` to an `int`. To do so you should do  `length1 = int(length1)` or do `length1 = int(input())` directly.

It depends on what do you expect the user to input, if it seems that you are assuming that the user will input an int so you can just restrict yourself to int. However, if you expect the user to input a float, you might want to use float instead. Hence rather than `length1=int(input())` do `length1=float(input())`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to multiply two floats (decimals) together

```py
print('A: Square or Rectangle')
print('B: Triangle')
print('C: Circle')
answer = input('What shape do you need? ')

if answer =='A':
    length1 = float(input('Enter first length: '))
    length2 = float(input('Enter second length: '))
    print('The area is '+length1*length2)
```

As stated in the comments, try to read a bit online about datatypes and inputs in python before coming here with a problem